# Insert a csv file into Azure SQL from an Azure Blob

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, azure

I have an asp.net (c#) site in Azure and an accompanying Azure SQL database.  I need to upload 1gb+ csv files and get them parsed and into my Azure SQL database.  I can get the csv files into an Azure blob.  I now have the URL to the blob (newGuid.txt).

Either from SQL or from the web app, how do I parse this csv and get it inserted into my Azure SQL database? (the csv has 36 columns if that helps)

I can't figure out how to reference the URL to use SqlBlukCopy.  I initially thought I would BULK INSERT but Azure SQL doesn't allow that.  I can't download the files locally and use BCP for each one.

Comment: instead of trying a sqlbulk copy I would suggest trying to bulk insert the data into the table using XML you can parse the data into a datatable then from there create a stored procedure which would comprise of a temp table and insert into the temp table the data in xml format.. I do this all the time to get around having to explicitly use sqlBulkInserts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree this is an old question, but as gets traction, here is the answer:

You can use [Azure Data Factory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/data-factory/) to move data from Blob Storage (and many more data sources) to Azure SQL Database (and many other data sinks).

There is nothing simpler today to achieve your goal. Here are some tutorials:

- [Move data by using Copy Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview)
- [Move data to and from Azure Blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage)
- [Move data to and from SQL Server running on-premises or on Azure VM (IaaS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database)

You can configure a data pipeline to just run once. Or run on specific time, or run on a schedule. You can make it copy single file, or using file pattern to get more files, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
          LOCATION = 'https://****************.blob.core.windows.net/invoices'
          , CREDENTIAL = MyAzureBlobStorageCredential --> CREDENTIAL is not required if a blob is configured for public (anonymous) access!
);

BULK INSERT Sales.Invoices
FROM 'inv-2017-12-08.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage');
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#f-import-data-from-a-file-in-azure-blob-storage