# How do I bulk insert into an Azure SQLServer Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I would like to do bulk inserts to my Azure database from Python, but I can't find the documentation for how it's done.

[This page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-data-science-move-sql-azure/) says:

> The following table summarizes the options for moving data to an Azure SQL Database.

The section [linked from that table](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-data-science-move-sql-azure/#bulk-insert-sql-query) says:

> The steps for the procedure using the Bulk Insert SQL Query are similar to those covered in the sections for moving data from a flat file source to SQL Server on an Azure VM.

And that provides the following query:

```
BULK INSERT <tablename>
FROM    
'<datafilename>'
WITH 
(
FirstRow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR =',', --this should be column separator in your data
ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'   --this should be the row separator in your data
)
```

But presumably that datafile has to live somewhere, but I can't find *where* in the documentation that it confirms where this data file should live. I can create a csv file and upload it as a blob to Azure storage, but [nobody in the last year had an answer for how get it from there to SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29633297/344286).

How can I bulk insert into SQL Azure?

Comment: the referenced question just got its answer! Your question however is specific to python, or I am missunderstanding something? If it is OK for you to get your CSV from Blob into SQL DB - check the answer to the referenced question. If you eagerly want to do this by hand with Python, re-write your question.

Comment: I think the data factory approach will be suitable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a csv file into Azure SQL from an Azure Blob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633297/insert-a-csv-file-into-azure-sql-from-an-azure-blob)

Comment: I cannot believe. I see this question every single week.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server vNext CTP supports T-SQL commands that load from Azure Blob Storage. This will be available in Azure SQL Database soon so you can use BULK INSERT command from your example to load data from Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is visiting this old question looking for the answer, as I did, Microsoft allows importing from Azure Blob Storage to Azure SQL now.

You will need a Shared Access Signature in case the Blob is not public. Here is an excerpt of the example directly from the Learn page:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH (TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
      LOCATION = 'https://****************.blob.core.windows.net/invoices'
);

BULK INSERT Sales.Invoices
FROM 'inv-2017-12-08.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage');
```

In the section [Import data from a file in Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&source=recommendations#f-import-data-from-a-file-in-azure-blob-storage) of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current&source=recommendations#f-import-data-from-a-file-in-azure-blob-storage) you can see more details about how to use encryption and SAS in case the blob is not public.

For people who use .NET, there is an alternative class `SqlBulkCopy` in the  `System.Data.SqlClient`. Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy).